# How to put system to sleep instead of hibernate?

Tags: suspend, power-management

I am a newbie to Ubuntu, there doesn't seem to be any option to put the laptop to sleep instead of hibernate (suspend). Is there any way to put it to sleep instead?

Comment: Which desktop session are you using (Unity/Xfce/GNOME/KDE etc), and what hardware are you using?

Comment: I should point out that suspend and hibernate are not the same thing. Suspend is synonymous to sleep, while hibernate saves machine state to the disk and powers off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for the first answer, yes, sleep is for shell (Now edited).
You can sleep (suspend) your system using **pm-utils** (installed for default on ubuntu) or **systemctl**.

```
pm-suspend
```

If you have installed **systemctl**, you can use direct interface for systemd

```
systemctl suspend
```

More info:
[Power Management / Reduced Power](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/ReducedPower)
[Systemd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#Power_management)